# Differentiate integers and strings in a file in unix

Tags: shell-script

I have a file which has below details

```
Feb07
Feb07
07:30
07:30
Feb07
Feb07
Feb07
Feb07
Feb07
Feb07
00:01
Mar07
July07
Feb07
Feb07
Error
15:09
15:09
```

I need a command where i can get the month(string characters) but not the integers. I want to write a script where if i find any character (Mar07,July07 etc) it should throw an alert. Please suggest

Comment: `grep [[:alpha:]] filename` will print only lines that have alphabetical characters in them.

Comment: To verify, for the given example, you'd want something printed for each Feb07, Mar07, and July07?

Answer (score 2):

The following command will output only alphabetic characters from the file:

```
$ grep -o '[[:alpha:]]*' file
Feb
Feb
Feb
Feb
Feb
Feb
Feb
Feb
Mar
July
Feb
Feb
Error
```